# How can I specify to xargs to run a command with all the arguments at once?

Tags: xargs

`xargs` has an option `-n` for specifying the maximum number of arguments to a command to run at each time.

Is there a way to specify that `xargs` should always run any command with all the provided arguments at once? (Just like running the command with all the arguments directly without `xargs`, I am not trying to avoid  failure due to system limit on command line length)

**The following is not my question. Please disregard it, if it distracts you.**
I don't want to use command substitution, because it removes `NUL` and trailing newlines, so I am considering to use `xargs` as an alternative. But I don't want `xargs` to group the args for several runs, because the results from multiple runs with different subsets of arguments can be different from results from single run with all the arguments, depending on the command that xargs executes. So I want to tell `xargs` to always run all the arguments at once.

Comment: One of tho _reasons_ for using `xargs` is that _very long_ lists of arguments simply can't be given to a utility in one go as the argument list has an upper length limit.  `xargs` will by default give as many arguments _as possible_ to the utility.  An example of your issue would be good to see (please [edit] your question).

Comment: If you want to pass chunks of data containing NULs via the command line (via the arguments to execve(2)), forget about it. This is not possible, in any language. If you want to bypass the length limit imposed by the OS on the args + env and run a prog with a huge nr of args, there may be hacky ways of doing it, but **not** with the standard tools.

Comment: Why is it not possible If you want to pass chunks of data containing NULs via the command line (via the arguments to execve(2))?@mosvy

Comment: Because NUL terminates individual arguments in `argv`.

Comment: Could you explain what you’re trying to do in a bit more detail? I imagine you’ve got either a file, or a command outputting some data, which you want to use as arguments for another command, but only run the latter command if you can do so with all the data as arguments — is that correct? Can the second command take its input from its standard input instead?

Comment: @StephenKitt `xargs ls` will ask for input from stdin instead of command line arg, and that is what I want. A command run by `xargs` might not give the same result before and after `xargs` groups the arguments, and that is what I want to avoid. These are questions but not really the question asked in my post.

Comment: And it’s apparent that `xargs` doesn’t meet all your requirements. If you explain what you’re actually trying to do (and not how you’re trying to use `xargs` to go about it), we might be able to suggest an alternative which doesn’t involve `xargs`.

Comment: @StephenKitt Is your answer to my post that xargs can't always run all arguments at once? What is some alternative to `xargs` for my distracting questions.

Comment: See Kusalananda’s first comment. The whole point of `xargs` is to not do what you’re trying to do. I can’t suggest an alternative without knowing the specifics of what you’re trying to do.

Comment: Trying to find a   nicer "command substitution", without removing anything or as few as possible. It doesn't matter that the system call execve() will remove NUL. I just want to pass all the content without change. @StephenKitt

Comment: _"I don't want to use command substitution, because it removes NUL and trailing newlines"_ , and _"`xargs` will ask for input from stdin, and that is what I want."_. -- Err, I'm not sure what the actual use case is here. Are you entering NUL bytes from the terminal manually, or... what?

Comment: either enter manually or from stdout of a previous command. @ilkkachu

Comment: You can't pass NUL characters as argument to a command anyway. `xargs` will either strip them or complain about them as well. Or do mean you want to use `xargs -0` on a NUL-delimited output?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Do you mean when xargs calls execve(), excve() will strip them, by "xargs will either strip them or complain about them"?  I don't want to use xargs -0 on a NUL-delimited output.

Comment: `execve()` takes a list of pointers to NUL-delimited string, so there can't be any NUL in those strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure I understand what you're after, but combining the `-x` option ("exit if the command line doesn't fit") with the `-n` option set to a huge value (larger than the system limit) should:

a) make sure `xargs` is run just once, no matter how many arguments are given to it

b) error out if the arguments could not be fit in a single command because of the OS or xargs-internal limit.

Example:

```
$ seq 1 10000 | xargs -n 100000000 -x sh -c 'echo "$#"' sh
10000
$ seq 1 100000 | xargs -n 100000000 -x sh -c 'echo "$#"' sh
xargs: argument list too long
```

Unfortunately, this does not work with the BSD or solaris' xargs. On *BSD, the `-x` option will cause `xargs` to run its command with a single argument, instead of exiting:

```
fz11_2$ jot 10000 1 | xargs -n 10000 -x sh -c 'echo $#' sh | head -3
1
1
1
xargs: sh: terminated with signal 13; aborting
```

Only some ridiculously small argument to `-s` will cause the `-x` to trigger:

```
fz11_2$ jot 10000 1 | xargs -s 19 -n 10000 -x sh -c 'echo $#' sh | head -3
xargs: insufficient space for arguments
```

The [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) seems to match the GNU xargs behavior:

> ```
> -n  number
>       Invoke utility using as many standard input arguments as
>       possible, up to number (a positive decimal integer) arguments
>       maximum. Fewer arguments shall be used if:
>       + The command line length accumulated exceeds the size specified
>         by the -s option (or {LINE_MAX} if there is no -s option).
>       + The last iteration has fewer than number, but not zero,
>         operands remaining.
> -x
>       Terminate if a constructed command line will not fit in the
>       implied or specified size (see the -s option above).
> ```

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is already the default.  `xargs -n` provides a maximum number of arguments to use, but if you don't specify it, `xargs` will use as many arguments as possible.

You mentioned the system limit in your question, and that you don't expect/need to circumvent that.  `xargs` will take that system limit into account, but may use a lower value, as described in the usage for the `--max-chars` (`-s`) option:

> ```
>  --max-chars=max-chars
>  -s max-chars
> ```
>
> Use  at  most  *max-chars* characters per command line, including the command and initial-arguments and the terminating nulls at the ends of the argument  strings.   The  largest  allowed
>   value  is system-dependent, and is calculated as the argument length limit for exec, less the
>   size of your environment, less 2048 bytes of headroom.  **If this value is  more  than  128KiB,
>   128Kib  is  used  as the default value; otherwise, the default value is the maximum.**  1KiB is 1024 bytes.

(emphasis mine)

You can check what it is with `echo | xargs --show-limits`.  Example output:

```
Your environment variables take up 3712 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2091392
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2087680
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
Maximum parallelism (--max-procs must be no greater): 2147483647
```

This shows that my hard limit is 2087680 (just under 2MiB).  If your system also permits more than 128K, you can prevent splitting by using `xargs -s 2087680` (adjust according to your own limit).

Older versions of `xargs` would even let you provide a higher limit than the OS permits.  With 4.4.2, a warning was displayed, but the specified value accepted anyway, and you get the same error that you would see from running the command directly:

```
$ seq 1 2000000 | xargs -s 2100000 echo | wc -l
xargs: value for -s option should be < 2092927
xargs: echo: Argument list too long
0
```

But in versions 4.6, the hard limit is respected:

```
$ seq 1 2000000 | xargs -s 2100000 echo | wc -l
xargs: value for -s option should be <= 2091392
23
```

Comment: I would like `xargs` to always run any command with all the arguments given at once.

Comment: Please could you show a situation in which it doesn't?

Comment: That is what my post is asking for.

Comment: No, your post doesn't show the situation where `xargs` is unsuitable.  It will only split if either `-n` is provided (which you're not doing) or the `--max-chars`/system limit is exceeded (which you've implied you're not reaching).

Comment: I was asking "Is there a way to specify that xargs should always run any command with all the provided arguments at once? (Just like running the command with all the arguments directly without xargs, I am not trying to avoid failure due to system limit on command line length)". The system limit can be reached, and I am looking for some way which makes `xargs`  fail.

Comment: Will you accept `xargs -s some_enormous_number`?

Comment: That is not the same. It still succeed by having a second run with extra arguments,  when the command line length exceeds the `-s` limit.

Answer (score 2):

Some clarifications:

In

```
cmd1 $(cmd2)
```

Here is what happens with the output of `cmd2`:

- in `bash`, the NULs are discarded. YMMV with other shells (in `zsh` they're preserved, some shells ignore everything after the first NUL).
- the trailing newline characters are removed
- the result is split according to `$IFS` whose default value is SPC, TAB, NL in most shells, SPC, TAB, NL, NUL in `zsh`.
- each work is subject to globbing (except in `zsh`). For instance `*` becomes the list of non-hidden files in the current directory.
- the resulting list is passed as arguments to  `cmd1`. The `execve()` system call to do that will fail if that list (combined with the environment) is too big (and in the case of Linux also if any single argument is larger than 128KiB).

In

```
cmd2 | xargs cmd1
```

Here's what happening with the output of `cmd2`:

- in some implementations, the bytes of that output are interpreted as characters. For instance in  a locale using a UTF-8 charset the e2 80 86 byte sequence makes up a U+2006 character which is the *SIX-PER-EM SPACE* character, often considered as a blanks character. If some bytes don't form valid characters, depending on the implementation, they may be removed or cause a failure, the behaviour is not specified by POSIX if the input is not text
- If there are NUL bytes, again, that's not text, so the behaviour varies with the implementation
- If there are lines that are bigger than LINE_MAX (which on some systems can be as low as 1024), the behaviour is also unspecified.
- `xargs` parses its input as per its own expected format. In that format, whitespace and newline characters are understood as delimiter (so trailing newlines would be split all the same) the list of which varies with the implementation (including that U+2006 for instance in some), and `'...'`, `"..."`, and backslash are used as quoting operators to prevent those delimiters and other quoting operators to be treated specially.
- that results in a list or *words*.
- in some implementations, if any of those words is `_`, it's treated as an end-of-file logical indicator and everything after it is ignored.
- if any of those words is larger than some limit (in many systems, as low as 255 bytes), the behaviour is unspecified.
- the remaining words are passed as arguments to `cmd1`, but if that list is too big, instead of failing like in the command substitution case, `xargs` tries to fit as many as possible (with a bit of margin which varies with the implementation) for `execve()` to succeed, and runs the command as many times as needed to use all the  arguments.

Now:

- if you wanted to pass the whole output of `cmd2` as one argument to `cmd1`:

  - if that output contains NUL characters, you can't as that's a limitation of the `execve()` system call, not command substitution nor `xargs`.
  - if that output is bigger than the ARG_MAX limit, you can't (though there are ways to increase that limit on some systems), again a limitation of `exexve()`. You could if `cmd1` was for instance a builtin or function of your shell (as there's no `execve()` involved then), but even then, in practice, only `zsh` supports arguments with NUL in that case.
  - on Linux, if it's bigger than 128KiB, you can't. That limit can't be raised.
  - Otherwise (if there's no NUL, and it's small enough), you can always do: `out=$(cmd2; echo .); cmd1 "${out%.}"` or with GNU `xargs`: `cmd2 | xargs -0 cmd1`

Comment: "If there are NUL bytes, again, that's not text, so the behaviour varies with the implementation". Do you mean the behaviour of xargs without -0? I guess xargs with -0 expects NUL bytes?

Comment: @Ben, yes `-0` is a GNU extension, out of scope of the POSIX specification anyway. `-0` is pretty simple and without surprises in all the implementations that support it and doesn't interpret the input as text, just sequences of bytes without any interpretation. GNU `xargs` used to be very buggy and unmaintained until the mid 2000s. The only thing you could rely on with it was `-0` back then.

Comment: What is GNU xargs' behavior If there is any line  bigger than LINE_MAX? (note that in GNU findutils' manual, LINE_MAX is not mentioned, and I guess it probably is named something else?) Is LINE_MAX the one overridded by -s?

Comment: "if any of those words is larger than some limit (in many systems, as low as 255 bytes), the behaviour is unspecified." Is the limit on a word length specified by some variable in Linux and in GNU xargs?

Comment: @Ben, GNU utilities generally don't have max line limits. Traditional Unix versions do as they tend to use plain stdio (`fgets()` and co) which also explains why they can't cope with NULs in input lines.

Comment: by "line", do you mean  the entire stdin input to xargs? not a command line that xargs constructs?

Comment: "The execve() system call to do that will fail if that list (combined with the environment) is too big (and in the case of Linux also if any single argument is larger than 128KiB)". Is 128KiB a different limit from ARG_MAX?

Comment: Yes, it's a different limit, and it's specific to Linux.

Comment: Thanks. The Linux Programming Interface says "On  Linux,  ARG_MAX  was  historically  fixed  at  32  pages  (i.e.,  131,072  bytes  on
Linux/x86-32), and included the space for overhead bytes. Starting with ker-
nel 2.6.23, the limit on the total space used for argv and environ can be con-
trolled via the RLIMIT_STACK resource limit, and a much larger limit is permitted
for  argv  and  environ.  The  limit  is  calculated  as  one-quarter  of  the  soft
RLIMIT_STACK resource limit that was in force at the time of the execve() call. For further details, see the execve(2) man page."